# How to programatically access the Eclipse variable pool?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pde

I have registered a handler through the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point and added an `enabledWhen` condition which checks the variable `selection` in the Eclipse variable pool. This works perfectly fine, but now I want to replicate this behavior to my SWT buttons which are displayed in a view.

My question is as follows: How can I access the Eclipse variable pool in order to get the `selection` variable to listen on selection events and subsequently call the `button.setEnabled(true/false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the selection service `ISelectionService` to listen for selection changes. In a view or editor you can get this using:

```
ISelectionService selectionService = getSite().getService(ISelectionService.class);
```

You can then use the

```
public void addSelectionListener(ISelectionListener listener);
```

method to listen to all selection changes or you can use

```
public void addSelectionListener(String partId, ISelectionListener listener);
```

to listen to selection changes in a particular part.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Works perfectly!