# How to access double click/selection change event listener in VariablesView plug-in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to retrieve variable details after the user selects a variable in the VariablesView and not before hand. How should I do that?

Comment: You can probably use the ISelectionService to listen to selection events from that view

Comment: Can I access the ISelectionService of the view without extending the VariablesView class? Probably I have to implement a CustomVariablesView  that extends VariablesView and override some method to access the ISelectionService.

Comment: The selection service is completely independent of any view, it is a service provided by  things like `IWorkbenchPage` (which extends `ISelectionService`). You must not  extend VariablesView, it is an internal class.

Comment: Again this will be the listener right, how do I get hold of the  select event notification without extending VariableView? Can you explain in bit more detail please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585695/how-to-programatically-access-the-eclipse-variable-pool

Comment: The code in that answer can be in any view or editor, it does not have to be the variables view. As I said the IWorkbenchPage also provides the ISelectionService, you can get the active page in any plug-in code. So you can put the listener anywhere that suits you.

Comment: How do I add listener to scroll event?